# I need to get a count from a Declare Statement with a Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Declare @trans table(eTransid varchar(30) Not NULL)

INSERT INTO @trans
SELECT DISTINCT eTransID
FROM csi_eRecording.dbo.eRecordAudit WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE EventMessage LIKE 'Recorded file cannot be found%' 
ORDER BY eTransID

SELECT a.*
FROM csi_eRecording.dbo.eRecordTrans a WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN @trans b ON a.eTransID=b.eTransID
ORDER BY eTransID
```

Comment: Count of what? After the INSERT or SELECT - @@ROWCOUNT will contain the cound of inserted/returned rows

Comment: I need a count of the records when I query it shows a total of 1221 rows I need to display that as a total

Comment: Its in the @@ROWCOUNT variable after the SELECT

Comment: Alex I'm a newbie so I don't understand what you are saying here? THanks

Comment: After the `SELECT` add `select 'total rows returned is', @@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: @AlexK. You should put that as an answer, as that's what it really is. Also, just for note, if you wanted it on each row for some reason (like you can only get one result out of this or something) you could use `COUNT(*) OVER() TotalCount` as a way to do that. But `@@ROWCOUNT` is really the right answer here. Also, here is a demonstration of what you said: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ff0c/11

Answer (score 1):

[`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) tracks the last count of affected rows

```
declare @trans table(eTransid varchar(30) Not NULL)
insert @trans values ('all'),('hail'),('cthulhu')

select 'inserted rows=', @@ROWCOUNT

--(No column name)  (No column name)
--inserted rows=    3

select * from @trans

--eTransid
--all
--hail
--cthulhu

select 'selected rows=', @@ROWCOUNT

--(No column name)  (No column name)
--selected rows=    3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*,(select count(*) FROM csi_eRecording.dbo.eRecordTrans a WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN @trans b ON a.eTransID=b.eTransID ORDER BY eTransID) as countIT FROM csi_eRecording.dbo.eRecordTrans a WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN @trans b ON a.eTransID=b.eTransID ORDER BY eTransID
```

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.